# How to use multiple labels to select a node in a Jenkins Pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

**Intro:**

We are currently running a Jenkins master with multiple slave nodes, each of which is currently tagged with a single label (e.g., `linux`, `windows`, ...)

In our scripted-pipeline scripts (which are defined in a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)), we currently use snippets like the following:

```
node ("linux") {
    // do something on a linux node
}
```

or

```
node ("windows") {
    // do something on a windows node
}
```

Yet, as our testing environment grows, we now have multiple different Linux environments, some of which have or do not have certain capabilities (e.g., some may be able to run service `X` and some may not).

I would like to label my slaves now with multiple lables, indicating their capabilities, for example:

- Slave 1: `linux`, `serviceX`, `serviceY`
- Slave 2: `linux`, `serviceX`, `serviceZ`

If I now need a Linux slave that is able to run service `X`, I wanted to do the following ([according to this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-node-code-allocate-node)):

```
node ("linux" && "serviceX") {
    // do something on a linux node that is able to run service X
}
```

Yet, this fails.
Sometime, also a `windows` slave gets selected, which is not what I want to achieve.

---

**Question:** How can i define multiple labels (and-combined) based on which a node gets selected in a Jenkins scripted pipepline script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `&&` needs to be part of the string, not the logical Groovy operator.

E.g.:

```
node ("linux && serviceX") {
    // do something on a linux node that is able to run service X
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: node( 'Docker || docker-containers' )

Comment: && does not work, here wrong answer is marked correct. JCompetence is correct you must use double pipe operator: node( 'Docker || docker-containers' )

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt For what was asked for in the question (the node has to be Linux AND has to offer serviceX AND has to offer serviceY), it has to be `&&`. With a `||` you would get *either* something that has the label `Docker` OR `docker-containers`, but may be missing the other. Kind of a weird thing to specify, indicates that whoever was in charge of maintaining the node cluster failed to stick to a single naming convention.

Comment: understood that, "&&" selects node with both labels.